# Codeigniter: Message: Call to a member function line() on null

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter:

I am doing this in language/english/pages/about-me_lang.php:

```
<?php echo $this->lang->line('url_Contact')?>
```

and I am given this error:

```
Message: Call to a member function line() on null
```

so $this doesn't have lang...

What should I use to get lang line variable?

And how to know that is $this anyway? I mean in the whole thing (Codeigniter)

Thanks

**Update 1:**

[image]

it is here, in these files that nothing with $this-> will work, like $this->load or $this->lang.

What is $this here and how to get $this that I can load files there?

**Update 2:**

> $this is applicable inside a class context.

So it means that a php file in views folder belongs to a class (is it from a controler class context?), but php file under language isn't, hm...

**Update 3:**

So, in view we have CI_Loader and based on this: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html

is responsible for what it is responsible :)

...but, under the language folder, we have a different thing:

```
because when I try: $this->load->model('functions');
```

i get:

```
Message: Undefined property: CI_Lang::$load
```

Now, how with CI_Lang class to get that variable?

**Update 4:**

Found the solution, posted it as separate answer down below!

Comment: Well you probably have to load the `lang` thing. because its not loaded it's null.  Something like `$this->load->library('lang');`  I forget it's been a minute.  It could be `language` too.  If you need it everywhere you can load it in, I want to say hooks maybe... I know there is a place to load it globally .. lol  look up the documentation.

Comment: $this is applicable inside a class context. Are you calling it outside a class? Also please share more code on where the $this->lang is initialized? What is the code inside about-me_lang.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a line of text from a language file, but INSIDE files that are under language folder this is the solution:

```
<?php echo $this->line('url_Contact')?>
```

because, the class context there is [CI_Lang](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html#fetching-a-line-of-text).

Thanks [Rinsad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10235271/rinsad-ahmed) for mantioning class context.

Answer (score 1):

Use `false` in the second argument, when not sure if the line exists

```
$this->lang->line('url_Contact', FALSE);
```

You can optionally pass FALSE as the second argument of that method to disable error logging, in case you’re not sure if the line exists

[Make sure the language class is loaded.](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/language.html#loading-a-language-file)

**[Check my answer on another question which explained well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097566/how-to-add-a-second-language-to-the-site/33097831#33097831)**.